# Know when an app has been programatically deleted

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

I uninstall an app programatically in Android, using an Intent, like you see below:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+packageName);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Which redirects to a prompt that asks if you want to uninstall the app.
Usually after that you can see a toast in the bottom of the screen saying the app was uninstalled. But I want to be able to be notified so I can remove an uninstall button in a view.

How can I know in the code when the uninstall of the package has been completed? Or if an error occurred? Or even, if user clicked "ok" to uninstall or "cancel" if he changed his mind, how can I know?
Is it possible to know any of this? Is there an alternative way to uninstall a package (without being a system app) and be notified?

Thank you for reading. Lemme know if you need any more information.

Comment: You could start with startActivityForResult(). Untested.

Comment: I suppose I can give that a try. Not sure if it will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up finding a solution, when a package is removed there is an intent that can be picked up by a receiver.

In my AndroidManifest

```
<application
        <!--...-->
        <receiver
            android:name=".UninstalledBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

Create a UninstalledBroadcastReceiver class that extends a normal BroadcastReceiver

```
public class UninstalledBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // handle the intent here
    }
}
```

You can check for instance if your package name of the app that was installed matches your own and do something with it. In my case, I put some static fields in the UninstalledBroadcastReceiver, including an interface so that I could perform some callbacks. Don't think you can pass fields in the constructor, since the object is created when the intent is received.